# BIRT,render parameter form

Tags: tomcat7, birt

I would like to integrate BIRT in a J2EE app. There is an excellent [tutorial](http://birtgrip.blogspot.de/2012/10/birt-integration-with-web-application.html) which explains the integration. To make a long story short, you need just to copy the libraries from "BIRT Runtime" into your EE project,write a servlet and a couple of classes to show the reports from your app.
To render the report you create IRenderTask instance and then invoke render() method.

```
IRenderTask iRenderTask= birtEngine.createRenderTask(reportDoc);
 .....
iRenderTask.render();
```

But how can I render the form for the input parameters if the report requires them,only using BIRT API. For example, something like this:

```
ReportParams params = getParameters(reportDoc)
ReportParamsFormRenderTask rpf = new ReportParamsFormRenderTask(params)
rpf.render()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We can get parameters informations through BIRT api with [IGetParameterDefinitionTask](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/deploy/reportEngineAPI.php#igetparameterdefinitiontask).
However there is not a render feature for this, we need to walk in parameters list using  this task and build an output with a JSP page, for example.

A more simple approach would be to display parameters values in a grid element at the beginning of birt reports, and use "visibility" property to hide/display this grid as we like, depending on a parameter value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. I decide to go in easier way )).
I ended up with the deploying "BIRT Runtime Release Build" which you can download from [link](http://download.eclipse.org/birt/downloads/).I've put all the libraries from it into my EE app, in the web.xml I defined servlet-mapping of already implemented "ViewerServlet":

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.eclipse.birt.report.servlet.ViewerServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
....

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ViewerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/frameset</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and the other required mappings (all the same like in BIRT Runtime Release Build web-app example).
The only point I do not understand, why it uses axis. I can not run reports if I do not put "server-config.wsdd" file in my WEB-INF folder.